# Issue On Using Text() in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am just getting the last item in the `.result`

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('.result').text('Hello' + [i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the source code within a new element.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('.result').append( $('<p>').text('<p>' + 'Hello' + [i] + '</p>') );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will replace the innerText of the element. To append the text, you need [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('.result').append(' Hello' + [i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

To check how `text()` works,

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.result').text(' Hello' + [i]);
    }, 1000 * i);
  }(i));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, the reson that I was willing to use the `text()` was because I  was passing HTML tags into the `.result` in fact I just need to generate source code through this function but by using the `append()` it is working by pure string but in case of passing HTMl it actually apply the markup into the page! any idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Because `.text()` set the text. It will set

```
Hello0 // when i=0  
Hello1 // when i=1  
Hello2 // when i=2  
Hello3 // when i=3  
Hello4 // when i=4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **always changing the content of div** and last text changed is **hello4**

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n6nrveyb/)

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   $('.result').html($('.result').html()+'Hello' + [i]);
}
```